# Text file reader only reads the first line

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to load every row in the text document into a list.
But for some reason, it only reads the first line and then exits.

I have used this exact file reading method and it worked without any problems. Now when I want to use it in the same way it doesn't work. I've tried different accounts of rows in the text document but it always exits the loop after the first row.

```
            //Reads the text file
        var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            //Adds the content of each line to a list
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                destinationEmails.Add(line);
            }
        }
```

I Expect all lines to be read and put in the list.

Comment: Have you debugged this?

Comment: Also why not use `File.ReadAllLines()`

Comment: Oh, `File.ReadAllLines()` Is so much more simpler. I'll switch to that instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `ReadAllLines()` to read all of the lines in the document. Update your code as following code.

```
    //Reads the text file
    var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        //Adds the content of each line to a list

        string line = string.Empty;

        while ((line = streamReader.ReadAllLines()) != null)
        {
            destinationEmails.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is actually wrong. `while ((line = streamReader.ReadAllLines()) != null)` will not do what you think it does.

Comment: That’s correct. In my opinion, after adding string.empty; the condition should be updated with !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line);. But the question is pointing something else.

Comment: I Tested both of your solutions and they worked good. The reason Hasans code worked was because he switched `ReadLine()` for `ReadAllLines()`. In the end i went with Michaels because it was shorter.